# db fetch array drupal 7

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I've an issue with a migration from a drupal 6 to 7 website. I'm a beginner in PHP and MySQL and I can't find a solution to my problem.

The code I'm struggling with is following:

```
$sql = "select ID_Speler from TB_Spelers where uid = ".$id;
$row = db_fetch_array(db_query($sql));
$speler = $row['ID_Speler'];
```

I always get a "Call to undefined function db_fetch_array()"

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/1032750

Answer (score 2):

Use this in Drupal 7:

```
$query = db_select('field_data_field_order_no', 'fdfon');
$query->addField('fdfon', 'entity_id', 'nid');
$query->addField('fdfnt', 'field_notification_type_value', 'type');
$query->join('field_data_field_notification_type', 'fdfnt', 'fdfon.entity_id = fdfnt.entity_id AND (fdfon.bundle = :fdfon_bundle AND fdfnt.bundle = :fdfnt_bundle)', array(':fdfon_bundle' => "order_notification_type", ':fdfnt_bundle' => "order_notification_type"));
$query->condition('fdfon.field_order_no_value', $order_id)->orderBy('fdfnt.entity_id', 'asc');

$result = $query->execute();

while ($records = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no `db_fetch_array()` in Drupal 7, the (almost) equivalent code would be

```
$sql = "select ID_Speler from TB_Spelers where uid = :uid";
$args = array(':uid' => $uid);
$row = db_query($sql, $args)->fetchObject();
$speler = $row->ID_Speler;
```

See the [Database API docs](https://drupal.org/developing/api/database) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:

```
 $sql = "select ID_Speler from TB_Spelers where uid = %d";
 $query = db_query($sql, $id);
 while ($records = db_fetch_array($query)) {
   $spelers[] = $records['ID_Speler'];
 }
 print_r($spelers);
```